# Is holodeck technology used on most planets in the Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek, holodeck

I would like to know if holodeck technology is a common amenity that is used on most planets in the Star Trek Universe. For example, are there large buildings that house large rooms with holodeck technology in which the general public can pay to have access to, or perhaps there are some wealthy people who can afford to build their own private holodeck within their home?

Is holodeck technology used on most planets in the Star Trek Universe?

Comment: One thing I don't think has ever been established is which race invented holographic technology and when

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I think there was an episode of Enterprise where Tucker experienced it, and it seemed like fully realised technology. So at the very least, it was created on or before 2151.

Comment: @Longshanks it wasn't clear, though, whether that civilization *invented* the holodeck or whether it was just something they had and humans didn't. Lots of other tech is treated that way - civilizations largely develop warp drive independently. It's like that in our own world too - India has The Bomb but Sri Lanka doesn't, but neither of them truly invented it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holodeck technology appears to be common on Federation planets (noting that Janeway grew up with the hologrammatic [Flotter](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Flotter) stories some 30+ years before we see the advanced holodeck in TNG: Encounter at Farpoint) but by no means within the grasp of most individuals. It looks like it's more of a 'common good' like a cinema or a park than a home entertainment product like a flat-screen TV.

In [DS9: Meridian](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/454.txt), Quark (the owner of a *set* of holosuites available to rent at very reasonable rates) marvels at the idea that someone might own something so extravagant for their sole use.

> **TIRON:** *You know, if this program is as good as you claim, I might just purchase it from you to use at home.*
>
> **QUARK:** (awestruck) *You... have your own holosuite... ?*
>
> **TIRON:** *Just a little present I bought myself...*
>
> [And with that he EXITS to the holosuite.  Quark watches the door shut behind him.]
>
> **QUARK:** (to himself) *His very own holosuite... it's good to have money...*

Given that the Federation has no millionaires, it seems more reasonable that you simply book time at a local holodeck amenity than that you own one yourself.